App for evaluating trainees
Does anyone know of an app/platform/website through which I can automate emailing weekly questions (MCQ style) to my trainees? Once they answer, they would get the answer sent to them and it would track how many questions each trainee is answering and how many they are getting correct. I am hoping I can just upload several questions at once and they'll get sent at a regular frequency automatically. Thanks!

Please see previous answers and discussion posted here, suggesting solutions like Moodle and Drupal Quiz .
This depends on whether you want the overhead of running full-blown systems. They both handle MCQ, and a lot more... Both can run on internet or intranet so that your students can log in and answer. You also automate emailing.
Also see NZART Trainer
